# Не могу сделать упоминание пользователя как Отображаемое имя в команде >аватар

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord, disnake

Я делал команду ">аватар" и у меня не получается найти отображаемое имя пользователя которое я у себя написал в профиль. То есть когда я пишу ">аватар" то пишет lordeyser#0 хотя я в отображаемое имя написал Гена букин помогите пожайлуста заменить этот атрибут на отображаемое имя. Ниже будет код. Заранее большое спасибо!

```
@bot.command(aliases=["Аватар"])
async def аватар(ctx, member: disnake.Member = None):
    member = member or ctx.author
    avatar_url = member.avatar.url if member.avatar else member.default_avatar.url
    embed = disnake.Embed(title=f"Аватар {member}", color=0xc80005)
    embed.set_image(url=avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Вот как реагирует бот на это сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После обновления дискорда (удаление тегов пользователей) это стало невозможным... Можно вывести только `lordseyer` (ваш ник, но не отображаемое имя):

```
@bot.command(aliases=["Аватар"])
async def аватар(ctx, member: disnake.Member = None):
    member = member or ctx.author
    avatar_url = member.avatar.url if member.avatar else member.default_avatar.url
    embed = disnake.Embed(title=f"Аватар {member.display_name}", color=0xc80005)
    embed.set_image(url=avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Ну или упоминание пользователя:

```
@bot.command(aliases=["Аватар"])
async def аватар(ctx, member: disnake.Member = None):
    member = member or ctx.author
    avatar_url = member.avatar.url if member.avatar else member.default_avatar.url
    embed = disnake.Embed(title=f"Аватар {member.mention}", color=0xc80005)
    embed.set_image(url=avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Знаете бота известного бота Juniperbot? у него эта функция работает но у меня нет посмотрите пожайлуста в чем проблема. Если найдете или не найдете напишите пожайлуста. заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Не нашёл) там как то по своему сделано